# Replace an img src in a Google Presentation, using Google Apps Script

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-docs, presentation

I'm writing an Apps Script to generate new Presentations, using a template that has text like {{session_name}}, {{speaker1_name}} etc.  The script goes through, and using a google spreadsheet row as the data source, replaces {{speaker1_name}} with "John Smith" from the source data, for example, and saves it as a new Presentation document.  The replacement is just done like this:

```
slide.replaceAllText('{{speaker1_name}}', new_val);
```

That's working, but i don't know how to handle images.  In the template, next to each person's name, email etc, there's a photo of them.  In the source data, there's a photo_src column, with the url of a headshot pic of that person.

If it was just a normal webpage then I would just update the `src` attribute of the image.  But how do I do the equivalent in a Google Presentation?  thanks

Comment: How are you adding the image to Google Sheets? by using a URL like `=image("URL")`? Or by adding the image to the cell using `Insert` > `Image`?

Comment: It's just sitting in my template file at the moment.  I'm asking how to replace the one in the template, after I make a copy of the template to start making a new doc.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to replace a shape including a placeholder text with an image on Google Slides using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

```js
function sample1() {
  const presentationId = "###"; // Please set your Google Slides ID.
  const url = "###"; // Please set the direct link of your image.

  const s = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  const slide = s.getSlides()[0]; // 1st slide.
  slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
    if (shape.getText().asString().trim() == "{{sample image1}}") {
      shape.replaceWithImage(url);
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, `{{sample image1}}` on the 1st slide is replaced with an image of `url`.

#### Sample script 2:

From your question, if you want to achieve your goal by retrieving the values from Spreadsheet, how about the following sample script?

In this sample script, as a sample situation, the values of `{{session_name}}`, `{{speaker1_name}}` and `{{sample image1}}` for replacing are put into columns "A", "B" and "C", respectively. Please be careful about this.

```js
function sample2() {
  const presentationId = "###"; // Please set your Google Slides ID.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const template = DriveApp.getFileById(presentationId);
  values.forEach(([session_name, speaker1_name, imageUrl], i) => {
    const t = template.makeCopy(`sample${i + 1}`);
    const slide = SlidesApp.openById(t.getId()).getSlides()[0]; // 1st slide
    slide.replaceAllText("{{session_name}}", session_name);
    slide.replaceAllText("{{speaker1_name}}", speaker1_name);
    if (imageUrl == "") return;
    slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
      if (shape.getText().asString().trim() == "{{sample image1}}") {
        shape.replaceWithImage(imageUrl);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, `{{session_name}}` and `{{speaker1_name}}` are replaced with the values in columns "A" and "B". And, `{{sample image1}}` is replaced with the direct link of the image in column "C".
- If you want to give the constant image size, you can use [setWidth(width)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#setWidth(Number)) and [setHeight(height)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/image#setHeight(Number)) of Class Image.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [replaceWithImage(imageUrl)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/shape#replacewithimageimageurl)

### Added:

When you want to use this script for multiple pages in a Google Slide, you can also use the following script.

```js
function sample2b() {
  const presentationId = "###"; // Please set your Google Slides ID.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const template = DriveApp.getFileById(presentationId);
  values.forEach(([session_name, speaker1_name, imageUrl], i) => {
    const t1 = template.makeCopy(`sample${i + 1}`);
    SlidesApp.openById(t1.getId()).getSlides().forEach(slide => {
      slide.replaceAllText("{{session_name}}", session_name);
      slide.replaceAllText("{{speaker1_name}}", speaker1_name);
      if (imageUrl == "") return;
      slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
        if (shape.getText().asString().trim() == "{{sample image1}}") {
          shape.replaceWithImage(imageUrl);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks - i can do the text replacement already, it's the image replacement i was asking about.  The template has an image in it already and I want to either replace that image with a new image with my desired src, **or** update the src of the existing image.   But, maybe it makes more sense to have `{{sample_image}}` in the template, rather than an actual image.

Comment: Actually that approach is nice because I actually have three 'entries' per page, each with name, email and photo, so I can put in {{sample_image1}}, {{sample_image2}} etc.  I didn't mention this in the original question for the sake of clarity but I like this approach.

Comment: I like this option too, I will reuse it in a project. Thanks @Tanaike.

Comment: @Max Williams Thank you for replying. When the image in a Slide is replaced with another image, I think that it is required to give an identification id to the image title and the image description for replacement. From this situation, in your situation, replacing the text placeholder with an image might be suitable. About using multiple pages in a Google Slide, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Max Williams By the way, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply and the current situation, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. If my answer was not useful, I apologize. At that time, please tell me. I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: @Giselle Valladares Thank you for your comment. If this will be useful, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike your answer didn't *directly* answer my question but it did suggest an alternative approach which might be better than what I was trying to do.  I haven't actually had a chance to try it yet.  it is definitely a useful answer so thank you.

Comment: @Max Williams Thank you for replying. From `I haven't actually had a chance to try it yet.`, if you have a question for my answer, feel free to tell me.